# Need Help for Custom vim command

Tags: regex, vim, arduino

I started using vim not long ago. I can't figure out how to achieve the following custom command:

I am working with Arduino sketches, that contain the ip address of the device running the sketch in the network like `my_ip = 192.168.10.x`

I would like to bind a custom Command like `:OtaUpload` to the following procedure:

1. search the active Document for the content of a variable e.g. `my_ip = <search_result>`
2. execute and wait until finished the following python command: `python /path/to/script.py -i <search_result> -f "<absolute_path_of_active_doc>/build/<name_of_active_doc>.bin"`

I know I can get the directory of the active doc with `%:p:h` and the name of the document with `%:t`, but I don't know how to concatenate them like i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be familiar with vimscript to make the most of vim. Hope this helps for you to get started.

```
function! Build(ip_prefix)
  call search(a:ip_prefix)
  let ip = matchstr(getline('.'), a:ip_prefix.'\zs.*')
  let cmd = 'python /path/to/script.py -i '.ip.' -f <absolute_path_of_active_doc>/build/<name_of_active_doc>.bin'

  echom ip
  echom cmd

  " Uncomment below when the cmd is ready
  " execute cmd
endfunction

command Build :call Build('my_ip=')

normal G
Build


" my_ip=192.168.10.x
```